# What is the equivalent of CGImageCreateWithImageInRect in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

What is the equivalent of CGImageCreateWithImageInRect iOS method in MonoTouch?

I'm trying to convert this Objective-C line in C#:

```
CGImageRef sampleImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, fillRect);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

The CoreGrapphics function **CGImageCreateWithImageInRect** correspond to the **WithImageInRect** method of **CGImage**. API signature is:

```
public CGImage WithImageInRect (RectangleF rect)
```

Once translated from ObjectiveC your source code should look like:

```
 CGImage sampleImageRef = this.CGImage.WithImageInRect (fillRect);
```

Comment: They're not actually in line with each other. CreateWithImageInRect takes into account the location of the rect, whereas WithImageInRect (the mono version) only takes into account the size of the rect. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect